# Passing a file name that starts with

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to build a python package that takes an input of a file that starts with "ElectronicsExport_"  the rest of the number is an encoded date and other information.  I would like to run something like this

I know in SQL its a like statement followed by a % but not sure what it would be or how to do this in python.

I've researched and not sure what question to ask on it

Running the following:
python CreateMapping.py ElectronicExport%

*****With the % being any file that starts with ElectronicExport
using python 3.7.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: This "like" should probably not be done by python but by the shell you launch python from. In most linux shells and windows shells this could be done using `*`, where `ElectronicExport_*` would then be expanded in a list of filenames starting with `ElectronicExport_` separated with spaces.

Comment: Use `startswith()` method in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method in python `startswith()` to check any string start with particular string value.If condition is true it returns `true` else `false`.

e.g

```
File_Name = "ElectronicsExport_23432"
if File_Name.startswith('ElectronicsExport_'):
    ## Your logic
    print("Match")
```

Output:

```
Match
```